# Getting error when I try to add image to product

Tags: product, theme

It's a simple product. It saves but when I try to add an image I get the 
parameter theme_dir not passed. I am using the magento blank template. It's a fresh 2.1 install and the magento blank template is selected as the theme for the website.

==> stage.blaircorner.com/html/var/log/exception.log <==
[2016-08-08 19:47:24] main.CRITICAL: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed' in /chroot/home/blaircornerc/stage.blaircorner.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Simple.php:61

Answer (score 0):

this had to do with the host nexcess modsecurity rules being triggered. They added some exceptions to these rule and could now make the save.